# Finding the p value for binary data

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, binary-data, contingency-tables

I have made an experiment with binary outcomes, and I struggle with calculating a p value to decide if it is significantly different than the control group.

There were two sets of identical cells: one treated with a specific molecule (Group 1), the other left untreated (Group 2). The results: out of 10 checked cells in Group 1, 7 died, whereas in Group 2 only 2 out of 10. Am I right, that I cannot use the t-Test for this type of data to decide if the difference is significant? What would be the appropriate method to calculate the p value (and where can I find some good resources that explain how to do it)?

I also have the possibility to check more than 10 cells, but it is quite time consuming. Is there a straightforward way to calculate an approximate N needed for significance?

Comment: Regarding sample size calculation, you'd need to specify the effect size you're looking for - finding a difference of 20% vs. 50% will require far fewer samples to achieve statistical significance compared to a situation where you're trying to find a statistically significant difference between 49% and 50%.

Answer (score 1):

For such small samples the common test to use is [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).  For larger samples you can use a Chi-Squared test or a 2-sample test of proportions.  There are tools available for estimating sample size/power for these types of tests, either in statistical packages or you can Google for web based tools.